# How can I identify the variables that contribute most to creating the partition between two clusters?

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, boxplot

This question is a follow on from a question I asked here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127208/how-do-i-correctly-plot-the-clusters-produced-from-a-cluster-analysis-in-matlab/39142286?noredirect=1#comment65632215_39142286

I have carried out hierarchical clustering in Matlab to create five clusters from my data with 200 observations and 10 variables:
What I want to know is how to statistically identify the variables in a cluster analysis that are the most different between clusters: ie. the variables that contribute most to creating the partition between two clusters? What I have done so far is to create boxplots of each of the variables across all the clusters in one graph...which allows me to graphically ascertain if a particular variable varies alot across clusters. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an idea: treat your 2 clusters as 2 classes. Create a binary model with 1 cluster as reference class. The most significant variables are the variables influencing the partition. You can look at statistics like p-value and chi-square to determine, which one is relatively more significant.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this approach. By binary model, do you mean sort of a 'presence absence' zeros and ones approach? I'm using matlab btw. It's important to note that the clusters will probably not be the same size.

Comment: Are you familiar with logistic model? You can combine your data and set any of the cluster data points to 1 and other to 0 and build a logistic model/ or any other binary model to understand the variable importance

Comment: If you want to avoid the exercise of model building, just compare the mean,standard deviation,variance of the variables in both the clusters. this  can be a quick method. Though you should be doing statistical tests for 2 groups(considering 2 clusters as 2 groups) like t-test,f-test etc.

Comment: I have fit the logistic function to data before, but that is as far as my experience goes with it. I think I'll have to try something like you have suggested though, as I do want to be able to definitively say why the clusters are different. There will be more than two clusters, but I can still try an approach similar to what you have suggested above to see what my outputs are like I suppose.